# Getting Susy to compile with Koala on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass, susy-sass, susy

Just started using SASS for the first time. Set it up with ruby on rails on my windows 8, and got it to work and compile with Koala compiler allright. I just need to use the Susy library, but I could not get it working. So far, i've installed the following:

```
1. Ruby, using ruby installer

2. Gems:
a. gem install rails
b. gem install sass
c. gem install susy
```

This doesn't seem to get susy working. The sass compiler keeps throwing errors whenever it encounters the Susy syntax. On their page they do mention to make sure sass-rails is version 5.0.0.beta1, but the ruby command prompt doesn't accept a command such as `gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'`. Is it that I have to enter this somewhere else? Or could it be that I need to use a different compiler?

Be gentle I'm new to this :D

Comment: Can you please show us the error? If you're using Rails, you're going to specify gems and versions in your gemfile.

Also, I highly suggest this: http://www.zell-weekeat.com/learnsusy/
It's *very* comprehensive.

PS: I'm really not sure why you get a negative vote for this question, but I've gone ahead and upvoted to (hopefully) counterbalance.

Comment: Hi, this was actually a while ago so I don't remember the exact error message since I got rid of Koala since then. I realized Koala just couldn't compile Susy, so I got myself Compass App and it worked. Codekit also works well. Thanks for the upvote! You know how some people are just malicious downvoters.